# Automatic "root object" detection implementation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Suppose I have two classes like this:

```
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        # How do I make this attribute (or property if I must change
        # it to one) automatically reference the root object (if the
        # current object is a an item of root.children)
        self.root = ???
```

So my question is partially already in the code, but it needs some clarification. Suppose I create objects from the class like so:

```
root_obj = Root()
child_obj = Child()
root_obj.children.append(child_obj)
```

How would I make it so `child_obj.root` automatically detects that the current object is being stored under `root_obj` and reference that object? This way, if I later decide to store `child_obj` inside a new object `another_root_obj.children` then `child_obj.root` will reference that object instead. If this is not possible the way I'm trying to do it, then what would be the correct way to design a system like this in Python?

Comment: create a method `add_child` that implements this would be the straightforward way... no? If `root.children` is a list, then there really is not way if you want to use `root.children.append`, since objects don't know if they are being appended to lists

Comment: I gave an answer below, but I could improve it if you specified exactly what you want to happen to the previous Root of an Child when it is assigned to another Root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic detection of being appended to a list is not possible.

Here are two ways that are close enough. You only need to go with one:

1. An ORM-like [`save(self)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) function.
2. Instead of appending child to root, assign root to child with Pythonic [`@property`](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) and `setter`.

```
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

    #1
    def save(self):
        for child in self.children:
            child.root = self

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = None

    #2
    @property
    def root(self):
        return self.__root

    #2
    @root.setter
    def root(self, root):
        self.__root = root
        if self not in root.children:
            root.children.append(self)
```

Usage for #1:

```
root_obj = Root()
child_obj = Child()

root_obj.children.append(child_obj)
root_obj.save()

print(child_obj.root) # <__main__.Root object at 0x05932890>
```

Usage for #2:

```
root_obj = Root()
child_obj = Child()

child_obj.root = root_obj

print(root_obj.children) # [<__main__.Child object at 0x060578F0>]
```

## Bonus

If you combine both, you can easily handle:

- reassignments, e.g. `child_obj.root = root_obj_2`

  - ...including edge cases, e.g. `child_obj.root = None`
- removal, e.g. `root_obj.children.remove(child_obj)` and then `root_obj.save()`

```
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
        self.__previous_children = []

    def save(self):
        diff = [c for c in self.__previous_children if c not in self.children]
        if len(diff) == 0 and len(self.__previous_children) == len(self.children):
            return
        for child in diff:
            child.root = None
        self.__previous_children = self.children.copy()
        for child in self.children:
            child.root = self

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = None

    @property
    def root(self):
        return self.__root

    @root.setter
    def root(self, root):
        if self.__root == root:
            return
        if self.__root is not None:
            try:
                self.__root.children.remove(self)
                self.__root.save()
            except:
                pass
        self.__root = root
        if root is None:
            return
        if self not in root.children:
            root.children.append(self)
            root.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

An object does not keep track of what references it. Mostly because this is rarely needed and would add a lot of complexity to garabage collection. So this is a behaviour you will have to implement yourself.

The following solution straightforwardly implements `add_child` and `remove_child` methods that will update the `Child`'s root.

```
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = set()

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.add(child)
        child.roots.add(self)

    def remove_child(self, child):
        if child in self.children:
            self.children.remove(child)
            child.roots.remove(self)

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.roots = set()

root_obj = Root()
child_obj = Child()

root_obj.add_child(child_obj)

child_obj.roots # {<__main__.Root object at 0x000001FDD5406048>}

root_obj.remove_child(child_obj)

child_obj.roots # set()
```